# how to draw Activity Diagram in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, uml, reverse-engineering

I have installed UML Netbeans plugin for reverse engineering that automatic convert my Java code into UML.

But my question is, how can I draw the activity diagram using the Netbeans plugin?

Whenever I select activity, sequence , collaboration or any other UML diagram instead class diagram  then only class diagram, it doesn't create the desired UML diagram.

Comment: The current Netbeans has NO UML plugin. It had it some time ago though. What tools do you really have? Versions, please.

Comment: Thanks for the answering Sir; I have Netbeans 7.2.1 and UML(6.0) version plugin.This tool make class diagram nice but could not other UML

Comment: 1. You are welcome, Sir. 2. Where have you got the UML plugin? It is not on the site of supported plugins. In which way you have installed it, for the standard plugin install won't work? 3. Please, edit your answer and put that versions info there.

Comment: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/1801/netbeans-uml
here is the link of Netbeans Plugin which I got it and this make my java coding into class diagram but diagram not producing .